# Mirror the color scale of a Seaborn heatmap, both colors and labels

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a heatmap produced with the Seaborn module as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlE0l.png).

As the values in the table generally increase with the distance from MSL (the values increase going down in the table), I want to mirror the color scale such that the dark blue color is at the bottom with the corresponding label (12), and the light yellow color is at the top, with label (3).

I only found a way to invert the colors, but then the labels remain in place. How can I mirror the entire scale (both colors and labels)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`invert_yaxis()` on the ax of the colorbar reverses both the ticklabels as well as the colorbar (`invert_xaxis()` does the same for a horizontal colorbar).

Seaborn's heatmap doesn't directly return a handle to the generated colorbar. It can be obtained via the plot's `ax`: `cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar`.

Here is an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(20), np.arange(20))
arr = (x * y) % 10
ax = sns.heatmap(arr, annot=True, cbar=True)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]